# Show that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_n$ converges $\implies \sum^{\infty}_{n=k}a_n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_n$ converges.

Show that for $k>0$ $\sum^{\infty}_{n=k}a_n$ converges.

May I have hints on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=0}^{k-1}a_n + \sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Simply note that

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=k}a_n=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_n -\overbrace{\left(a_o+a_1+\ldots+a_{k-1}\right)}^{\text{finite number of terms}}$$