# Prove that the following series converges using comparsion test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following series:
$$
\sum_{n= 1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3}{2^{\ln^2n}}
$$
and I want to prove that this series converges using comparison test. I already tried with $b_n := 1/2^n$ and $c_n := 1/e^n$ but it didn't work. Which series can I try ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use that eventually

$$2^{\ln^2n}\ge n^5$$

that is for $n\ge n_0$ such that $$\ln^2 n \ge 5\cdot \log_2 n \implies n\ge  e^{\frac 5 {\log 2}}\approx1357.6$$

then

$$\sum_{n= n_0}^{\infty}\frac{n^3}{2^{\ln^2n}}\le \sum_{n= n_0}^{\infty}\frac{n^3}{n^5}=\sum_{n= n_0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$$

Refer also to the related

- [Show that $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_n$ converges $\implies \sum^{\infty}_{n=k}a_n$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3433188/505767)